# FacebookSDK on Android - SharePhotoContent with Message body

Tags: libgdx, facebook-android-sdk, android-sdk-tools, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have a button in my game where I make a finish level screen capture , I then attach that picture to a Facebook SharePhotoContent dialog from the newest SDK.

It all works as it's supposed but how do I also insert a custom message body so that I replace the standard "*Say something about this photo*" text in the body?

Here is the code :

```
File tmpFile = new File(path_to_saved_facebook);
media_scanner = new SingleMediaScanner(this, tmpFile);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path_to_saved_facebook, options);
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
        .setUserGenerated(true)
        .setBitmap(bitmap)
        .setCaption("Latest score")
        .build();
SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
        .addPhoto(photo)
        .build();
shareDialog.show(content);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Facebook does not allow you to prefill the status message.

Comment: I'm reading this : https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#control . **Why would it state** "_Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the person can edit or remove the content before sharing."_  **if you ain't able o prefill**?

Comment: If you have the publish_actions permission, then you can upload a photo directly (without using the share dialog). In that case, you can specify a "message" along with the publish, and that's where the paragraph above applies. For the share dialog, there's no option to prefill.

Comment: Would be nice to allow the programmer to infill the ShareDialog also with the help of the publish_actions permission . At least with the ShareDialog the user has the chance to modify the text before posting it.

Comment: The right way to do publish_actions is to present a dialog where the user can type in the message they want to set. Apps that violate this policy can be disabled from using the platform. For our dialogs, we enforce the policy where we can, and in this case, we don't allow apps to set the message.

Answer (score 0):

pre-fill text-with-image is no longer work in latest SDK 4.0 or high 
Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the person can edit or remove the content before sharing.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill